# Draw line and shapes with more sharpness

Tags: python, pyqt5

Am using pyqt5 and Python in my program which is drawing shapes.
My problem is after am drawing my shapes when I zoom in they look in a really bad way like the image below.
I want to get sharpness like in the SVG image.
So how to get these results in pyqt5?

This what I get:
[image]

And this what I want:
[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 900, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pen styles')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawLines(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLines(self, qp):
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)

        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 40, 800, 800)




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you edit this question with the code that you used. Might help answering the question better!

Comment: I added some main lines of the code, Actually, the code is too large , but this code how am drawing the lines from Qpainter which is from QT

Comment: I just want to get a better drawing that I get, I want like SVG images too sharp and the other drawing programs like "yEd" and many..

Comment: @Moaaz please providea [mre]

Comment: AS you can see that code above, if you run it, you will notice the line is not a good quality  as I expected, I don't know how to explain it, but the pixels are really bad

Comment: @Moaaz can you please add `qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)` *after* `qp.begin(self)` and test again?

Comment: @ThomasWeller not *inside*, *after*. You cannot set render hints if the painter is not active (it's not documented, but Qt shows an alert if done before that); normally, it's not a problem, as QPainter is usually created with the paint device in the constructor (`qp = QPainter(self)` is the same as `qp = QPainter(); qp.begin(self)`)

Comment: @ThomasWeller if you're referring to your example, it's not reset because you used the QPainter constructor with the paint device (the pixmap): the painter is already active at that point, so your later call to `begin()` is ignored (as also stated in the stdout warning). If you create QPainter *without* the paint device and try to set the pen (which also raises another warning about the painter not being active), then the default pen is restored when `begin()` is called. This is because you can theoretically *reuse* a QPainter by calling again `begin()` after `end()`.

Comment: @musicamante: ok, I see. Guess I learned something

Comment: @musicamante: cleaning up comments. Your proposal works.

Answer (score 1):

By default QPainter only uses the `TextAntialiasing` render hint, so shapes are always aliased.

In order to draw "smooth" lines, you need to activate the `Antialiasing` hint.

Note that you don't need to call `begin()` if you provide the paint device in the QPainter constructor, and since it's a local variable in the scope of `paintEvent()` you don't need to call `end()` either, as it will be called anyway when the painter is destroyed by the garbage collector when the function returns.

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    qp = QPainter(self)
    qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
    self.drawLines(qp)
```